# Posting a tweet C#

Tags: c#, twitter, stack-overflow, tweetsharp

I am trying to post a tweet with TweetSharp library but a `StackOverflowException` is thrown. I couldn't solve this problem. What should I do? The error occurs in this line:

```
servis.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = textBox1.Text });
```

Comment: Show more of your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down and step through in the debugger (put a break-point on the `string status = ...` line):

```
// if you don't get this far, the problem is elsewhere

// if it fails here, the problem is accessing the textbox value
string status = textBox1.Text;

// if it fails here, the problem is inside the tweetsharp library,
// and should be referred to the library authors, but indicating which
// step fails (constructor vs Status property vs Send method)
var msg = new SendTweetOptions();
msg.Status = status;
servis.SendTweet(msg);
```